# Modal: how to save a value and display it in the page

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a webpage which has a button 'change'. When you click that button, a modal appears where it asks the user to enter a number.I need to be able to save the number entered by the user and display it in the webpage. I have created the modal inside a form, but i'm not sure how I display the changes in the webpage.
It's like this:

```
 <a   class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moneyModal">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-money glyphicon-white"></span>Change</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="moneyModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

        <form method="post" action="change-goal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Change Goal</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Please enter a new number.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input class="form-control" name="newGoal" id="newGoal">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

> So, my question would be how do I display the value entered by the
>   user in the input field(id=newGoal) after clicking the 'save' button.
>   Would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how that would work - I added jQuery and the Bootstrap CSS and JS to this snippet to reproduce your environment.

The little bit of JavaScript I added will fire when the `#save` button (an ID that I assigned) is clicked in the modal, and will put the text from the `#newGoal` field into the a new `#value` span I made.

Also, I changed `type="submit"` to `type="button"` on the modal button (so it doesn't do a real form submission and reload the page), and I added the `data-dismiss` attribute to it so it would also close the modal when clicked.

```js
$('#save').on('click', function() {
  $('#value').text( $('#newGoal').val() );
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moneyModal">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-money glyphicon-white"></span>Change</a>
  
<p>Your Number: <span id="value"></span></p>

<div class="modal fade" id="moneyModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <form method="post" action="change-goal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Change Goal</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Please enter a new number.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input class="form-control" name="newGoal" id="newGoal">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button id="save" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked.Thanks! what do i need to in order to save the value so that when I refresh the page, the value is still there

Comment: Start a new question for that - that will require cookies or something server-side.

Answer (score 0):

check out the code sample below, it should do what you intend doing using dom referencing to get the changes and updating page, and also making use of bootstrap actions for modals such as the `.modal('hide')`. From bootstrap doc

> hide: Manually hides a modal. Returns to the caller before the modal has actually been hidden (i.e. before the hidden.bs.modal event occurs).

then observe the form i used id to reference the DOMs so we can manipulate the views with it, when the form is submitted

Hope, this help.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

/**
using when the form is closed, we update the view 
*/
$("#formTest").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
  var nameGoal = $(this).find("[name=newGoal]").val();
 //we update our view here now
 $("#update").html("name goal: <b>"+nameGoal+"</b>");
 $("#moneyModal").modal('hide');//close our modal now
});


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <a   class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moneyModal">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-money glyphicon-white"></span>Change</a>
 
<div id="update">
am going to update here
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="moneyModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

        <form id="formTest" method="post" action="change-goal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Change Goal</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Please enter a new number.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input class="form-control" name="newGoal" id="newGoal">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: will this save it such that the value is still there when I reload the page? if not what do I need to do?

Comment: you can use local storage to save it, then get from the localstorage when you need it